# Davening whilst on a road-trip, what must I do?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, travel, shacharis-morning-prayer

If I'm driving long distance on a road-trip, (approx. 400 miles, leaving house at 3am, arriving at approximately 9am) am I required to stop the car, get out, and daven Shacharit at or before sunrise? Is there a way I can daven while still driving? If I were to get an audio recording of a chazzan leading the service, say amen at the right points etc., would this count?

Those that I'm going with are not Jewish, so it'd be kind of awkward to tell them to wait in the car for an hour.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but it sounds like you will be arriving at your destination before z'man tefilla is over. If so, it is certainly better to daven properly once you've arrived than to daven while traveling in a car.

Comment: While I agree with @jake's comment and Alex's answer, you should definitely [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) rather than rely on this site for practical questions.

Comment: can you be a passenger during the time it takes you to pray and then take over driving afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jake pointed out in his comment, if you'll be arriving by 9 AM, then just daven when you reach your destination.

If you're going to be on the road during the entire timeframe for Shacharis, though, then you can stop for just Shema and Shemoneh Esrei (those shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes or so), and say the rest of Shacharis while driving. (It is true that there are parts that it's customary to stand for, but that's just that - a custom, not an absolute halachic requirement.)

A recording wouldn't help for any of this. It's questionable whether you can fulfill your obligation by hearing a berachah (or whatever) live over the telephone or radio or whatever; but as far as I know it's undisputed that a pre-recorded voice doesn't count for anything.

Comment: Also, if you will arrive after z'man k'rias shema, you can say sh'ma in the car with the intention of repeating it later with the rest of shacharis after arrival.

Comment: I'd advise against praying while driving.  If you are a passenger, that is a different story.