# Exercise before Shacharis

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, sport-athletics

Halacha tells us that there are certain activities that are forbidden to do before one davens the morning prayer. Would exercise be one of those activities ?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for sharing the question! Consider registering your account to unlock more features of the site. Consider also taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. Hope to see you around the site.

Comment: I doubt all sorts of exercise would be forbidden and certainly you're allowed to run to shul. IF the purpose of the exercise is to make you more "awake" and "healthy" such that you pray better it is most likely permitted. Eating before prayer is considered "haughty" thus forbidden.

Comment: What about showering ?

Comment: @Selef1110, feel free to [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

I found

1 [Torah Musings](http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/12/before-the-shacharit-prayer/) says

> Minor activities are not considered to be work, nor a fulfillment of
>   one’s own desires, and they are therefore permissible before prayer.
>   For example, a person is permitted to make his bed before praying, and
>   he is permitted to take the garbage from his house to the public
>   garbage bin. Similarly, he is permitted to read the newspaper a bit
>   and **do a little exercise before prayer.**

(No source given).

2 [Kollel Iyun Hadaf](https://www.mail-archive.com/daf-discuss@shemayisrael.co.il/msg01705.html)

> The Shulchan Aruch (OC 89:3) says that it is forbidden for a person to
>   involve himself in his own needs before davening.  This certainly
>   includes eating and drinking before davening which Chazal say is an
>   expression of haughtiness; exercise is a grayer area.  The Rema (ibid)
>   though adds though that there are those that are lenient in this
>   matter if the person has said some of his Berachos.
>
> If the exercise is being done for health maintenance (and not for
>   pleasure) and  it is difficult to do it after davening, then it is
>   seems there is room for  doing it before davening provided that the
>   person says Birchos haShachar before  hand.
>
> Kol Tuv, Yonasan Sigler    *This is not meant to be a Psak Halachah.

3) israel.aish.com (Review Sheet for The Times of Davening - (Orach Chaim:Siman 89, 232-234)

> a) If a person needs to exercise before davening in order to have
>   strength to serve Hashem and he can’t do it later then this is also
>   Maleches Shamayim.

Conclusion:
Minor exercise is permitted.
If it cannot be done later, then exercise for health (after saying brochos) or to have strength to serve Hashem is permitted.

CYLOR.